# How to get informed about EVERY incoming ssh connection (e.g. with no remote command specified)

Tags: security, login, ssh-tunneling, sshd, tunneling

## The case

I'm used to set up automatic reverse ssh tunnels to remote computers via my server with `cron`.

Usually I use the following entry:

```
@reboot sleep 300 && ssh -MNf -R xxx22:host:22 user@server.com
```

I want to detect when such connection happens. I would like to have some script invoked automatically on connect event.

## The problem

However because of `-N` option standard SSH's tools (ones I'm aware about) do not work.
i.e. `/etc/ssh/sshrc`, `ForceCommand` and similar configuration features won't help me.

## Question

So is there anything inside of SSH itself to help me or should I dig into `grep`ing `log`s/`iptables`/whatever to deal with the issue?

Comment: I don't think there is such thing inside `sshd`. The only thing ssh does is logging. `fail2ban` picks authentication failures from the error/access log. You can also tweak ssh to provide you this information, but it is probably not standard way.

Comment: Using strace to monitor SSH connections on Linux.https://blog.netspi.com/using-strace-to-monitor-ssh-connections-on-linux/